# Git: move part from one repo to other repo with history

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have two git repositories: repo1 and repo2. repo1 contains folders "dir_a", "dir_b" and other. How I can transfer all files including git history from dir_a and dir_b of repo1 to repo2?

I've found some helpful article for such task: http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history. However, it is not fully suitable for me because I need to transfer 2 directories.

Comment: Are the two directories related? Do they form a library that you want to extract? Why do you want to extract them and what is the relation of repo1 and repo2?

Comment: True I don't think you can specify multiple subdirectories to `git filter-branch`, but doesn't it work to repeat the instructions of this article for every directory you want to move?

Answer (score 1):

> How I can transfer all files including git history from dir_a and dir_b of repo1 to repo2?

You can use `git filter-branch` and or `git subtree split`

#### Sample code:

## ***`filter-branch`***

```
# Filter the master branch to your directory and remove empty commits
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter YOUR_FOLDER_NAME filter_from_branch
```

This will checkout all your desired files from the given folder to the current directory

---

## ***`subtree split`***

> ***`git subtree`***
> `git-subtree` - **`Merge`** subtrees together or **`split`** repository into subtrees

```
git subtree split -P <name-of-folder> -b <name-of-new-branch>
```

[image]